# How to get Android's default dimension constants

Tags: android, material-design, android-elevation

Is it possible to get a reference to the xml defined dimensions that Android itself uses?

I'm using material design and noticed that a Button has a default elevation > 0. I want some of my custom elements to sit above the button (in the z dimension) and thought that a good way to do this might be to get a reference to the dimension value that the button uses and set my dimension to that value. However, I can't figure out how or if it's possible to get a reference to that value.

Here's the file that contains the value I'm after:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/res/res/anim/button_state_list_anim_material.xml

If the route I'm pursuing isn't feasible, does anyone have any suggestions for maintaining intended z ordering in Material Design since elevations can override the 'normal' z ordering of ViewGroups?